# UIImagePickerController get Image URL with Swift

Tags: ios, swift, image, file

I have a `UIImagePickerController` to let the user select a image, as i want to upload this image i would need the image "localURL".
Is there a way to get this localURL from my picker.

```
@IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    imagePicker.delegate = self
}

@IBAction func loadImageButtonTapped(sender: AnyObject) {
    imagePicker.allowsEditing = false
    imagePicker.sourceType = .PhotoLibrary
    presentViewController(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
}


func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : AnyObject]) {
    if let pickedImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage {
        imageView.contentMode = .ScaleAspectFit
        imageView.image = pickedImage
    }

    dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
}


func imagePickerControllerDidCancel(picker: UIImagePickerController) {
    dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You won't get any local url since you don't have access to images outside of your app container.

You don't need the file for transmitting the image, `NSData` should be perfectly fine.  I suggest you transform it to `NSData` like this

```
let imageData: NSData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(pickedImage)
```

Update: as i said, you won't have access to the actual file. The only way to have the image as file is to store it yourself.

in your update you showed some code for persisting the image yourself, which makes sense. It will be more performant if you use the ’pickedImage’ when setting your ’imageView.image’ instead of writing the image file and reading it, transforming it to an ’UIImage’ and then setting it as ’imageView.image’

I still havent really figured out, why you need the image as file and not simply send the ’NSData’ to your server. Maybe that is an option worth considering for you

Comment: your workaround (btw you should post that as edit in your question) is not really efficient, since you are writing the file and then reading the image for the image view again - while you still have access to the pickedImage 

Can you explain, why you specifically need the image as a file?

Comment: i need it as file as i upload it to a server via SSH after selecting

Comment: I updated my answer. Still dont understand why you can't send NSData to your server, but maybe there some special circumstances. Because usually, nsdata is the way to go

Answer (score 0):

as work around i do save the image,

```
  if let data = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(pickedImage, 0.8) {
                let filename = getDocumentsDirectory().stringByAppendingPathComponent("image.jpg")
                data.writeToFile(filename, atomically: true)
                print("file saved as image.jpg")
                print(filename)

                var image = UIImage(contentsOfFile: filename)
                imageView.image = image

            }
```